# Rambam and Torah Lishma

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rambam, mussar-ethics, mesilas-yesharim

The Rambam (Teshuva 10:2) defines the ideal motivation of performing mitzvot as (lishma) one "who does the truth because it is the truth".

On the other hand, the Mesilat Yesharim defines the ideal motivation (in ch.19) as to bring nachat ruach (pleasure/gratification) to God.

Are these two saying the same thing in different words or are they two different views?

Update: I see also in the Rambam's commentary on Mishnayot end of Makot: "Among the fundamental principles of our faith in the torah is that when a person fulfills one of the 613 mitzvot properly and befittingly, and does not associate with it in any way whatsoever any intent of this world but instead does it for its own sake (lishma), **out of love**".

Comment: Note that the Perush HaMishna was written in Arabic. It is therefore difficult to make an inference about how Rambam understood a particular Hebrew word (in this case: לשמה).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49974/discussion-on-question-by-ray-rambam-and-torah-lishma).

Comment: Doing it out of love is mentioned in Hilchot Teshuva 10:2 as well!

Comment: I would say that they're basically saying the same thing with each using their own terminology. Rambam's God doesn't derive pleasure from our good actions vs the kabbalistic God that does

Comment: @Nahum worth noting that a) many "kabbalists" feel they are not disagreeing with the Rambam and b) any divisions goes back way before "philosophy vs kabbalah". See Heschel's Heavenly Torah

Comment: @RabbiKaii We're discussing Rambam and Ramchal here. That's what I commented regarding. In any event Rambam is quite clear regarding his position and any reading to the contrary would be forced and agenda driven. As far as Heschel is concerned, to use the Talmud idiom: אי לאו דדלאי לך חספא, לא משכחת מרגניתא תותה.

Comment: @Nahum thanks for clarifying it was just about Ramchal's Kabbalah. I have heard that there is specific reason to think the Ramchal disagreed with Rambam on several points, could you point me to it? Your other comments are neither here nor there, and I won't be drawn into a debate about how clear the Rambam was, or about Heschel

Comment: @RabbiKaii I'm not looking to enter into a debate either. You raised those issues and I responded to them. To your question I am unable to search after specific sources at this moment but with Rambam essentially an aristotelian philosoper with a judaic bent and Ramchal a kabbalist the better q to my mind would be what DO they agree on

Answer (score 0):

Review the previous chapters of Mesilat Yisharim about *tahara*, and you will find Rambam's *shita*. He described this purity as definitionally "doing it for the sake of heaven":

> וּמִי שֶׁהוּא עוֹבֵד ה' בֶּאֱמֶת, לֹא יִסְתַּפֵּק בָּזֶה בְּמֻעָט
> וְלֹא יִתְרַצֶּה לָקַחַת כֶּסֶף מְעֹרָב בְּסִיגִים וּבְדִילִים,
> דְּהַיְנוּ, עֲבוֹדָה מְעֹרֶבֶת בִּפְנִיּוֹת לֹא טוֹבוֹת, אֶלָּא
> הַזַּךְ וְהַטָּהוֹר כָּרָאוּי, וְאָז יִקָּרֵא עוֹשֶׂה מִצְוָה
> כְּמַאֲמָרָהּ, שֶׁעָלָיו אָמְרוּ זַ"ל (שבת ס"ג א): כָּל הָעוֹשֶׂה
> מִצְוָה כְּמַאֲמָרָהּ אֵין מְבַשְּׂרִין אוֹתוֹ בְּשׂוֹרוֹת רָעוֹת.
> וְכֵן אָמְרוּ זַ"ל (נדרים ס"ב א): **עֲשֵׂה דְּבָרִים לְשֵׁם פָּעֳלָם
> וְדַבֵּר בָּהֶם לִשְׁמָן.**
>
> He who is truly a servant of G-d, will not be satisfied with serving
> Him minimally. He will not be content to take silver mixed with dross
> and lead, that is, divine service mixed with impure motivations, but
> rather only with the clean and pure as is befitting. Then he will be
> called "one who does a mitzva as it is stated", of which our sages of
> blessed memory said: "whoever does a mitzva as it is stated, will
> receive no evil tidings" (Shab.63a). Likewise they said: **"do [good]
> deeds for the sake of their Maker, and speak of them for their own
> sake"** (Nedarim 62a).

And what is this motivation that is clean and pure? Serving Hashem because it is the right thing to do i.e. because it is true:

> וְעִנְיָנָהּ **שֶׁלֹּא יַנִּיחַ הָאָדָם מָקוֹם לַיֵּצֶר**
> בְּמַעֲשָׂיו, אֶלָּא יִהְיוּ **כָּל מַעֲשָׂיו עַל צַד הַחָכְמָה
> וְהַיִּרְאָה** וְלֹא עַל צַד הַחֵטְא וְהַתַּאֲוָה.
>
> Its matter is for a man to **not leave any room in one's deeds for the
> evil inclination**, but rather, that **all of his deeds be from the
> side of wisdom and fear of G-d**, and not from the side of sin and
> lust.

I.e. pure motivations, based on the truth of the value of the actions themselves, and the One Who commands them.

> כִּי אֵין דַּי לָאָדוֹן בָּרוּךְ הוּא בַּמַּעֲשִׂים לְבַדָּם
> שֶׁיִּהְיוּ מַעֲשֵׂי מִצְוָה, אֶלָּא הָעִקָּר לְפָנָיו שֶׁהַלֵּב
> יִהְיֶה טָהוֹר **לְכַוֵּן בָּהּ לַעֲבוֹדָה אֲמִתִּית**.
>
> For to the Master of the world, the deeds alone are not sufficient,
> namely, to perform an act of mitzva. Rather, the primary importance
> before Him is that the heart be pure, **so that its intent is to true
> service**.

The introduction to chapter 19, as you brought, explains that there is a level above this, and that is not to do it just because it is right, true and wise, but also because you love Hashem, with a simple love that seeks only to please Him. This is yet another level of "*lishma*", which I believe the Rambam covers in the same halachot, e.g.:

> וּמַעֲלָה זוֹ הִיא מַעֲלָה גְּדוֹלָה מְאֹד וְאֵין כָּל חָכָם זוֹכֶה
> לָהּ. וְהִיא מַעֲלַת אַבְרָהָם אָבִינוּ שֶׁקְּרָאוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ
> בָּרוּךְ הוּא אוֹהֲבוֹ לְפִי שֶׁלֹּא עָבַד אֶלָּא מֵאַהֲבָה
>
> This is a very high level which is not merited by every wise man. It
> is the level of our Patriarch, Abraham, whom God described as, "he who
> loved Me," for his service was only motivated by love.